# "Your browser does not support charts" error in IE8 thrown for Google Chart

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using IE8 in IE Standards Document Mode and keep getting the above error. It's the actual IE8, not an emulator. The chart renders perfectly in Firefox and Chrome. It's not wrapped by any iframes. It works for both IE7 and IE8 Compatability View.

I think I had seen every post there is regarding this issue, be it Stackoverflow, Google Groups or what not, and couldn't find any real solution.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks a lot in advance.